# President Daily Diary - more info?

Tags: united-states, president

I recently discovered the staff of the President of the United States keep a diary recording what the president does for every minute of every day. I couldn't really find anything about this online, so I would like to ask if you know more about them. eg when this custom was started, why, do other countries have similar records, etc.

Comment: It's not "Every minute of every day", but it is an outline of the day.  See the [elder Bush's diary](http://millercenter.org/scripps/archive/documents/ghb/diary) for example

Answer (score 1):

The presidential diaries are generally constructed after the fact [by historians](http://www.whitehousehistory.org/whha_about/research-presidential-recordings.html) and researchers.  It's based on the log of White House visitors, Secret Service records, the presidential various written schedules, and notes from staffers (as well as news reports and other information sources).  It is compiled as a research effort and may often be accessed as part of the presidential library.

Note that this is separate from the mere visitor logs and schedules that are kept contemporaneously within a term and may be used to make political attacks on an administration (e.g. "conspiring with special interests").  This information is usually [open to the public](http://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/disclosures/visitor-records) today, though it requires journalists to sift through the data to make connections to various affiliations and then count the relative frequency of one constituency relative to another (e.g. ten times as often meeting X representatives versus Y representatives).

This is also distinct from a personal "diary" or journal that a president may keep for recording personal impressions, observations, state of mind, etc.  These may also be released to the public, perhaps with personal correspondence.  But the phrase "presidential diaries" tends to denote the compiled log and schedule of a President's meetings and movements, not a personal journal.

Obviously this sort of information is recorded for administrative reasons, to better manage the affairs of the administration and the movement of the President, and for Secret Service reasons.  It's compiled post hoc by historians to get a better sense of all presidents and of particular Presidents.

Comment: Which category are the Bush logs I linked above?  It looked like it was just the "visitor logs & schedules" type, but I only briefly glanced at them.

Comment: Those were compiled by researchers, archivists, and historians for use in connection with his presidential library.  It's a mixture of sources pulled together after the fact by specialists.  The first link has his schedule, a Marine helicopter manifest, gate list, Cabinet Affairs Office records, etc.